# Does <NuxtLink> have SEO advantages over programatic navigation?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

So I have a list of objects each rendered in a list. At the same time, each list element should redirect to a specific route on click:

```html
<template>
  <b-container>
    <h1 v-if="error">{{error}}</h1>
    <b-table
      sort-icon-left
      borderless
      outlined
      v-else-if="coins"
      @row-clicked="coinRowClickHandler"
      selectable
      small
      :items="coins" 
      :fields="fields">
      <template #cell(coin)="data">
        <NuxtLink :to="`/${data.item.name}/dashboard`"><img :src="data.item.image" width="25" height="25"><b>{{data.item.name}}</b></NuxtLink>
      </template>
      <template #cell(current_price)="data">
        {{ formatDollar(data.item.current_price, 20, 2) }}
      </template>
      <template #cell(price_change_percentage_24h)="data">
        {{ formatPercent(data.item.price_change_percentage_24h) }}
      </template>
      <template #cell(market_cap)="data">
        {{ formatDollar(data.item.market_cap, 20, 0) }}
      </template>
    </b-table>
    <b-spinner v-else/>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

As you can see, there is a click handler for each row click, the handler is the following:

```js
coinRowClickHandler: function(event) {
  console.log(event)
  this.$router.push(`/${event.name}/dashboard`)
}
```

Now I am unsure which navigation method to use; whether using `<NuxtLink>` or programatically via `this.$router.push`.

The main reason I would keep the programatic navigation is simply because I do not know any other way to trigger page change on row click. On the other hand, I am afraid I would lose SEO advantages of `<NuxtLink>` Tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<nuxt-link>` is basically a `<router-link>`, so it should have 0 benefit SEO-wise over the Vue variant.

As of what to use in your case, it's more a matter of `button` vs `a:href`. If you want to navigate to another page, it should be a link.

More details in this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/02/buttons-interfaces/

Comment: Why do `<NuxtLink>` tags have no SEO benefits? If I understand correctly, search engine crawlers can read links.

Comment: What I mean is that `<nuxt-link>` === `<router-link>`. It's just an SSR wrapper on top of the Vue one. I'd say that having links is better overall, because it can be crawled.

Answer (score -1):

Other advantages when using `nuxt-link` Nuxt can automatically prefetch pages with the `prefetchLinks` and `prefetchPayloads` options.

[prefetchlinks](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#prefetchLinks)

[prefetchpayloads](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#prefetchPayloads)

Comment: Is it somehow related to SEO?

Comment: No it is not related